# Issue in creating portfolio, if internal PDF size is large

Tags: java, pdf, itext, portfolio

While creating portfolio pdf, if any pdf size is large or it is having large no if pages in it, then portfolio pdf is not getting created. It does not throw any error as well. Please find the code below:

```
 public byte[] createPortFolio(String directoryName) throws DocumentException, IOException {

    Document document = new Document();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("This document contains a collection of PDFs, one per Stanley Kubrick movie."));

    PdfIndirectReference parentFolderObjectReference = writer.getPdfIndirectReference();
    PdfDictionary parentFolderObject = GetFolderDictionary(folderCount);
    parentFolderObject.put(PdfName.NAME, new PdfString("Root"));

    PdfCollection collection = new PdfCollection(PdfCollection.CUSTOM);
    PdfCollectionSchema schema = getCollectionSchema();
    collection.setSchema(schema);

    PdfCollectionSort sort = new PdfCollectionSort("File");
    sort.setSortOrder(true);
    collection.setSort(sort);
    collection.put(new PdfName("Folders"), parentFolderObjectReference);
    writer.setCollection(collection);
    listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(writer, collection, schema, directoryName, parentFolderObject, parentFolderObjectReference);

    document.close();

    return baos.toByteArray();
}

 public void listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(PdfWriter writer, PdfCollection collection, PdfCollectionSchema schema, String directoryName, PdfDictionary parentFolderObject, PdfIndirectReference parentIndirectReference) throws DocumentException, IOException {

    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    //get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    String sStatus = "";

    PdfIndirectReference siblingFolderObjectReference = null;
    PdfDictionary siblingFolderObject = null;

    PdfIndirectReference childFolderObjectReference = null;
    PdfDictionary childFolderObject = null;

    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            createPdf(writer, schema, file, parentFolderObject);//adding PDF in Portfolio
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            childFolderObjectReference = writer.getPdfIndirectReference();
            folderCount++;
            if (siblingFolderObject != null && parentIndirectReference.equals(siblingFolderObject.get(PdfName.PARENT))) {
                siblingFolderObject.put(PdfName.NEXT, childFolderObjectReference);
                writer.addToBody(siblingFolderObject, siblingFolderObjectReference);
            } else {
                parentFolderObject.put(new PdfName("Child"), childFolderObjectReference);
            }

            childFolderObject = GetFolderDictionary(folderCount);
            childFolderObject.put(PdfName.NAME, new PdfString(file.getName()));
            childFolderObject.put(PdfName.PARENT, parentIndirectReference);
            siblingFolderObjectReference = childFolderObjectReference;
            siblingFolderObject = childFolderObject;

            writer.addToBody(parentFolderObject, parentIndirectReference);
            writer.addToBody(childFolderObject, childFolderObjectReference);

            listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(writer, collection, schema, file.getAbsolutePath(), childFolderObject, childFolderObjectReference);
        }
    }
}
private void createPdf(PdfWriter writer, PdfCollectionSchema schema, File fileObj, PdfDictionary parentFolderObject) {

    PdfFileSpecification fs=null;
    PdfCollectionItem item;

    //Adding first File
    try{
        fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, fileObj.getPath(), fileObj.getName(), null, true, null, null);
        //fs=fileEmbedded(writer, fileObj.getPath(), fileObj.getName(), null, true, null, null);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("in Exception   "+ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("in finally block");
    }

    item = new PdfCollectionItem(schema);
    item.addItem("Type", "pdf");
    fs.addCollectionItem(item);

    try{
        writer.addFileAttachment(fs);   
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("in Exception2    "+ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

        System.out.println("in finally 2");
    }

}
```

In createPdf() function, after first try block code neither runs nor throws any exception.

Comment: What exactly is a *large pdf size* in this context? 10 MB? 100 MB? 1 GB? 10 GB? And what is a *large number of pages*? 100? 1000? 10000?

Comment: Pdf size is 339 MB and noOFPages are 932.